# What would you call anything that you achieve without any try

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

What do you call something like wealth, property etc. that you win or receive or somehow achieve from someone or somewhere unexpectedly and with no try? I know the word **windfall** which is can only be used for an unexpected amount of money. But how about i.e. a house which after dying one's aunt because of lacking an inheritor gets belonged to you? Or what would you call a founded bag full of dollars?

In my language, any belonging and property or amount of money which you have not tried for its achievement litterally is called **wind-brought**; which means the blowing wind has brought it to you that thing which requires no any diligence!

Some adjectives that I have come across are as below:

> - **easy** money/property/house.
>
>   - **gravy** money/property/house.
>   - **God-sent** money/property/house.
>   - **fast** money/property/house.
>   - **quick** money/property/house.

Regarding "money" I think the best noun would be **windfall**, but I don't know what a native would use in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windfall** -- OED says "A casual or unexpected acquisition or advantage."

Windfall doesn't have to be by surprise, but does have to be unearned. Inheritance from aunt, bag of money on street are all windfalls.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single word, but you could say that the house [*fell into your lap*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+into+lap).

> #### fall into (one's) lap
>
> To be received unexpectedly or without effort.
>   *I didn't steal the internship from you—it fell into my lap, I swear!*
>   *Your aunt has decided to get a new car, so her old one might fall into your lap.*